# Dynamic Tag Generation in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to dynamically generate a form using an array that contains a bunch of directive names

```
$scope.components = ["textbox", "textbox", "radio", "checkbox", "label"];
```

I want to generate tags with these names using angular. For example

```
<textbox></textbox>
<textbox></textbox>
<radio></radio>
<checkbox></checkbox>
<label></label>

<--THE FOLLOWING DOESN'T WORK BUT WOULD BE COOL IF IT DID-->
<{{component}} ng-repeat="component in components track by $index"></{{component}}>
```

Right now as an alternative I do the following

```
<div ng-include="component + '.html'" ng-repeat="component in components track by $index"></div>
```

Which basically does what the directive would do with the templateUrl parameter. Should I

- make a directive that generates tags
- continue using ng-include as I am
- use another method

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without understanding the bigger picture of what you're trying to achieve. Do you have any problems with your current approach?

Comment: I agree, if its not broke don't fix it, I was just curious what the best practice would be...who knows maybe there is some hidden gem of which I can take advantage of in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't generate tag of elements dynamically using only angular expressions. However you can create a custom `directive` to do that work for you.

**Proof of concept:**  ([Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ssJUAtzWk0Eh8EZVwcGc?p=preview): inspect DOM tree to see generated elements)

```
angular.module('MyModule').directive('dynamicTag', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      components: '&components'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      var components = angular.isFunction($scope.components) ? $scope.components() : [];
      var domElements = [];
      angular.forEach(components, function(c) {
        var domElement = document.createElement(c);
        $compile(domElement)($scope);
        domElements.push(domElement);
      });
      $element.replaceWith(domElements);
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<dynamic-tag components="components"></dynamic-tag>
```

being `components` an array of strings in the scope as in your question:

`$scope.components = ['textbox', 'radio', 'checkbox', 'label'];`

Comment: would you happen to know how to recompile the document afterwards? the directives dont naturally response to the new elements http://plnkr.co/edit/dfcJ5DUOJJ3u1KYGa3kE?p=preview

Comment: yap, use **compile service** to do so. I edited the answer. I added one line to the directive and changed the demo link.