# How to bind a directive from the Controller into the HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose i have a directive **CARD**

```
.directive('card', [function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E', // Element directive,
      templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/card.html'
  };
```

and a controller say **CARDCONTROLLER**

```
.controller('cardController',function($scope){
 $scope.directivename = 'card';
});
```

and a HTML file say **CARD.HTML**

```
<div>
 <{{directivename}}></{{directivename}}>
</div>
```

But the above doesnot work.

Does any one have any idea about how to accomplish this?

EDIT.
I dont want to generate the directive dynamically.Its just that i want to bind it through the controller without/with changing anything in directive

Comment: Here is a similar question [Dynamic Tag Generation in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574333/dynamic-tag-generation-in-angular).

Answer (score 0):

you must add the controller to your directive.

```
.directive('card', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E', // Element directive,
      templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/card.html',
      controller: 'cardController'
  }
})
```

this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

call your directive like,

```
<div>
  <data-card>
    // add code 
  </data-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define controller in your directive also

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/card.html',
controller: function($scope) {
  //write your controller code here


},
controllerAs: 'myController'
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see the below snippet , you will get idea how you can do this.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);


app.directive('card',function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E', // Element directive,
      template: '<h5>I am directive template</h5>'
  };
  });


app.controller('cardController',function($scope,$compile,$element){
$scope.directivename = 'card';
  
  var template = $compile("<"+$scope.directivename+"/>")($scope);
  
  $element.append(template);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="cardController">
  
</div>
```